# How to get user's location at the hangouts chat bot using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, geolocation, google-hangouts

I created a hangouts chat bot using apps script. I would like to access user's geographical location.

For example, when a user connects to the bot, the bot should greet the user with the user's location, such as longitude, latitude. I assume the users are using hangouts-chat in chrome browser. I am not sure whether this is even possible since the bot is at google's server side hosting the apps script code.

```
function onMessage(event) {
  var msg = event.message;
  var input = event.message.text;
  var name = event.user.displayName;;
  // code here to tell user's location
  return {"text":"your location is:"+sth};
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)